# Robocopy with Wildcard in Source

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I'm trying to write a script to copy a folder from one network location to another.  Inside the source folder, there are a number of folders with approximately the following structure:

> FL_411_Date
>   Flight_412_Date
>   FLT_413_Date

My goal is to copy only a specific folder, using the number in the folder name as an identifier.

Is it possible to use robocopy in this way?

My current command looks like this:

```
robocopy "\\\source\\*%FlightNumber%*" "\\\destination" /e
```

However, this doesn't work, the wildcards aren't recognized in the source path.  Any suggestions as to how to go about this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read `help for` and play with this one-liner in the command line

```
for /d %a in (*%flightnumber%*) do robocopy %a \destination /e
```

or in a more complete bat file

```
pushd "%source%"
for /d %%a in (*%flightnumber%*) do robocopy "%%a" "%destination%\%%a" /e
popd
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes things easier, wasn't aware of that syntax.